# Different results between fpc::dbscan and dbscan::dbscan

Tags: r, dbscan

I want to implement DBSCAN in R on some GPS coordinates. I have a distance matrix (dist_matrix) that I fed into the following functions:

dbscan::dbscan(dis_matrix, eps=50, minPts = 5,borderPoints=TRUE)
fpc::dbscan(dis_matrix,eps = 50,MinPts = 5,method = "dist")

and Im getting very different results from both functions in terms of number of clusters and if a point is a noise point or belongs to a cluster. Basically, the results are inconsistent between two algorithms. I have no clue why they generate these very different results although here
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/wiki.php?id_contents=7940
we see for iris data, both functions did the same.

my distance matrix [is coming from a function (geosphere::distm) which calculates the spatial distance between more than 2000 coordinates.

Furthermore, I coded dbscan according to this psuedo-code
source: https://cse.buffalo.edu/~jing/cse601/fa13/materials/clustering_density.pdf
My results are equal to what I obtained from fpc package.
Can anyone notice why they are different. I already looked into both functions and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of `geosphere::distm` says that it does not return a `dist` object but a matrix. `dbscan::dbscan` assumes that you have a data matrix and not distances. Convert your matrix into a `dist` object with `as.dist` first. THis should resolve the problem.